# Adding a .click(function(){ } to a div

Tags: jquery, html, click

So I want it so I alternate different `<p>` with different id's.
here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quote2").hide();
    $("#quote3").hide();            
    $("#quotes").click(function(){
            if(!$("#quote1").is(":visible") && $("quote3").is(":visible")){
                $('quote3').hide();
                $("quote1").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            if(!$("quote2").is(":visible") && $("quote1").is(":visible")){
                $("quote1").hide();
                $("quote2").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            if(!$("quote3").is(":visible") && $("quote2").is(":visible")){
                $("quote2").hide();
                $("quote3").fadeIn('slow');
            }
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to click the `<div>` with the id `#quotes` and then it will alternate the `<p>` (quote1,2,3)
But what I have is not working. Can I not add .click to a `<div>`?

EDIT:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#quotes").hide();
        $("#quote2").hide();
        $("#quote3").hide();
        $("#quotes").click(function(){
            var that = $(this),
            ps = that.find('p'),
            i = that.find('p:visible').index();
            that.find('p').hide().eq(i + 1 < ps.length ? i + 1 : 0).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
```

Works perfectly thank you David Thomas

Comment: I have more than 1 <div> tag so I didn't use $("div") instead of $("#quotes")

Comment: Yes you can add `click` event to a `div`.

Comment: I think you'll need to post your markup aswell.

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: If you have more than 1 Div use classes instead of ids and `$('quote1')` etc point to nothing, should it be `$('.quote1')` or `$('#quote1')` instead ?

Comment: You forgot your `#` in most of your selectors. E.g. `$("quote1")`

Comment: you are not putting the `#`

Comment: and what is the result of this ?

Comment: @j08691 Didn't notice, thank you. Helped a lot.

Comment: @mlwacosmos When you click the `<div>` it goes to the next quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest simplifying things (a *lot*), to:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var that = $(this),
        ps = that.find('p'),
        i = that.find('p:visible').index();
    that.find('p').hide().eq(i + 1 < ps.length ? i + 1 : 0).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F2Rsn/).

This answer is, however, based on the assumption that your HTML mark-up is, or resembles:

```
<div>
    <p>Quote 1</p>
    <p>Quote 2</p>
    <p>Quote 3</p>
</div>
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).